# Can an infinite subset of $\omega$ be Dedekind-finite in ZF?

Tags: set-theory

Can an infinite subset of $\omega$ be Dedekind-finite in ZF?

Say a set $X$ is infinite if for every $y \in \omega$ there is an injection from $y$ to $X$.  And say $X$ is Dedekind-finite if there is no injection from $\omega$ to $X$.  Equivalently, $X$ is infinite and Dedekind-finite iff its Hartogs number is $\omega$.  Is it consistent for a set $X \subset \omega$ to have this property?

I have found references showing that is possible to have $X \subset \mathbb{R}$, but these may be assuming countable choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No: if $X$ is well-orderable and infinite, then $X$ is Dedekind-infinite, and every subset of a well-orderable set is well-orderable.

Specifically:

- Since $X$ is well-orderable, by transfinite recursion $X$ is in bijection with some ordinal $\alpha$.
- Since $X$ is infinite, $\alpha\ge\omega$.
- OK, so look at the preimage of $\omega$ under that bijection ...

---

A related result in spirit is that no linearly orderable set can be *amorphous* (= not partitionable into two infinite sets): if $X$ is linearly ordered by $\trianglelefteq$, let $L$ be the set of elements with infinitely many things $\trianglerighteq$ them, and $R$ be the set of elements with infinitely many things $\trianglelefteq$ them.

If $R\cap L\not=\emptyset$, then any element of the intersection induces a partition of $X$ into two infinite pieces; so $R\cap L=\emptyset$. This means that exactly one of $R, L$ is infinite.

Without loss of generality, suppose it's $L$. Since no element of $L$ is in $R$, we know that $L$ - thought of as a linear order in its own right - has the finite predecessor property. But the only infinite linear order with the finite predecessor property is $\omega$ - so $X$ isn't even Dedekind-finite!

*Note that this argument **doesn't** prevent the existence linearly-orderable infinite Dedekind-finite sets; the point is that we used the assumption that $X$ was amorphous in analyzing $R\cap L$.*

In a certain sense, this is the main obstacle: while it is not possible to have an amorphous set of reals, it is possible (in ZF) to have an amorphous set of *sets of* reals.

Comment: Can we go further and say that an infinite Dedekind-finite set contains no ordinals at all?  We can specify $Y \subset X$, the set of all ordinals in $X$.  If $Y$ is infinite then there is an injection to $Y$ from $\omega$ by your argument, which is also an injection to $X$.  But if $Y$ is finite and non-empty we can specify $X \setminus Y$, so $X$ would have to be the union of two finite sets, contradiction.  Is that right?

Comment: @DanBrumleve No Dedekind finite set can contain infinitely many ordinals, but it can contain finitely many ordinals (why should $X\setminus Y$ be finite?) - note that $A\cup B$ is Dedekind-finite whenever $A, B$ are each Dedekind-finite, so take $B$ to be a finite set of ordinals ...

Comment: Ok, I'm getting it now, I was confusing "has no countably infinite proper subset" with "every proper subset is finite".  So when $Y$ is finite, $X \setminus Y$ is infinite and Dedekind-finite just like $X$ is.

Comment: Next question is can a subset of $V_\omega$ be infinite and Dedekind-finite?  I think no, because there is a class function that bijects between $\omega$ and $V_\omega$?  Or do we need some choice for that?

Comment: @Dan: Any cardinality related proof you can run on the ordinals, you can run on any set that can provably be well-ordered. Cardinality tends to be preserved by bijections.

Comment: @DanBrumleve It is provable in much much less than ZF that $V_\omega$ is in bijection with $\omega$. The first moment where you have anything interesting happen is $V_{\omega+1}$ which is morally equivalent to $\mathbb{R}$ (and in particular, theories much much weaker than ZF prove $V_{\omega+1}\equiv\mathbb{R}$).

Comment: Thanks guys for all your help  I think the thing that I need to internalize aside from the definitions is how to get transfinite recursion from replacement

Answer (score 2):

No. If $X\subseteq\omega$ then the map $x\mapsto|\{y\in X:y\lt x\}|$ is a bijection from $X$ to some finite ordinal or to $\omega.$